# openstack instance task_state stuck in powering off, how reset it to None

Tags: task, state, instance, openstack

An instance execute `shutdown` in operation system, and the `power_state` is `Shutdown`, but the `vm_state` is `active` without shutdown the instance through API, and Why the `task_state` is always `powering-off`, event never execute other operation by API.

Maybe the compute node memory is not enough at that time, and this instance was been killing, but now the compute node memory is satisfy.

How can I set the `task_state` to `None` without change the database info?

```
openstack server show

| OS-EXT-STS:power_state              | Shutdown         | 
| OS-EXT-STS:task_state               | powering-off     | 
| OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                 | active           | 


openstack server reboot --hard

Cannot 'reboot' instance instance-ID while it is in task_state powering-off (HTTP 409) (Request-ID: reqest-ID)
```

`openstack server set --property OS-EXT-STS:task_state=None instance` not work, the `openstack server show` output not change.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of text. Edit your question and replace the screenshots with text, and add more context. For example, I have no idea what the live-migration screenshot has to do with your problem. It would also be useful to know which OpenStack version this is.

Comment: Sometimes reboot takes a long time. I thought I had an instance stuck in hard reboot but after almost an hour it did eventually reboot and come back to running state. So, the answer might be to wait a bit longer in some cases if this is happening to you.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by restart the nova-compute server `docker restart nova_compute`.

Reference https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/1593186

Answer (score 0):

you can reset the task_state using

```
nova reset-state --active <id>
```